# jQuery Mobile listview in tabs and rendering problems

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, cordova, jquery-mobile-listview

I'm writing a very simple app in PhoneGap + jQuery Mobile.
The aim is to become more confident in writing PhoneGap applications.

The app is very simple: it has an HomePage with a navbar.
The navbar has three buttons: Contacts, Calendar and Docs.

The buttons manage three tabs in the `<div data-role="content">` element.
I have hidden those three tabs.
When the user tap on the navbar, I can navigate through the tab correctly.

Now, the problem: I successfully load the Contacts in the first tab but, when I navigate to it, I see only the dividers!
Instead, if I do not hide the Contact tab in the home, I can see the contacts correctly.
I'd like to load all the data while the user is still in the home page. So, while he decide what to do, the app should has enough time to load them.

The following screenshots show what I mean:

[image]
[image: Contact tab only]

Why does this happens?
If you need my code, here it is (only significant part! ;) )

HTML:

```
    <!-- Home jQueryMobile page -->
    <div data-role="page" id="homePage" data-dom-cache="true">

        <!-- Header -->
        <div data-role="header" id="homePageHeader" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>Frankie App</h1>
        </div>

        <!-- android style navbar. If the device is not an android, it
         will not be shown -->
        <div data-role="navbar" id="androidNavBar" hidden>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="showTab(contactsTab)">Contatti</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="showTab(calendarTab)">Calendario</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="showTab(docsTab)">Documenti</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <!-- Page content: it contains 4 tabs. The home + the 3 tabs reachable by the navbar-->
        <div data-role="content">
            <div id="homeLogger" hidden>Logger</div> <!-- I use this div as a console to debug -->
            <div id="tabs">
                <div id="homeTab">
                    <p align="center">
                    <img src="http://leaderchat.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/bigstock_cartoon_frankenstein_moster_as_151295541.jpg" height="280"/>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div id="contactsTab">
                    <h1>Contacts</h1>
                    <ul id="contactList" data-role="listview" data-autodividers="true" data-inset="true">
                    </ul>

                </div>
                <div id="calendarTab" hidden>
                    <h1> Calendar </h1>
                </div>
                <div id="docsTab" hidden>
                    <h1> Documents </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <!-- Footer -->
        <div data-role="footer" id="homePageFooter" data-position="fixed">
            <!-- iOS style navbar. If the device is not an iPhone, it
             will not be shown -->
            <div data-role="navbar" id="iOSNavBar" hidden>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="showTab(contactsTab)">Contatti</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="showTab(calendarTab)">Calendario</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="showTab(docsTab)">Documenti</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
$('#homePage')
   .bind('pageinit',
      function(){
        //Comment the next line to remove the logger from the home page
        $("#homeLogger").show();

        $("#homeLogger").text("jQuery Initialized");

        //Registering to PhoneGap/Cordova lifecycle events
        $(document).bind('deviceready', initialize)

      });

// ============ //
// Initializers //
// ============ //
function initialize()
{
     $("#homeLogger").text("device ready");
     initNavBar();
     initContacts();
}

function initNavBar()
{
//Retrieve the device platform using PhoneGap
platform = window.device.platform;
$("#homeLogger").text("detected platform: "+platform);
var navbar = null;
if(platform && platform == Constants.ANDROID){
    navbar = $("#androidNavBar");
    $("#homeLogger").text("show Android navBar");
} else {
    //If the platform is not an android, I keep the bottom
    //navbar because I prefer its look
    navbar = $("#iOSNavBar");
    $("#homeLogger").text("show iOS navBar");
}

    if(navbar) //safety check to avoid null reference.
        navbar.show(); //jQuery show() method
}

function initContacts(){
    $("#homeLogger").text("loading contacts...");


    var contManager = new ContactManager();
    contManager.getAllContacts(["id", "name"],
                           function(retrievedContacts){


                                for(var i=0; i<retrievedContacts.length; i++){
                                    var toAppend = "<li><a href='#'>"+retrievedContacts[i].name.formatted+"</a></li>";
                                    $("#contactList").append(toAppend);
                                    $("#homeLogger").text("element appended "+i);
                                }
                                $("#homeLogger").text("element "+$("#contactListview"));
                                $("#contactList").listview('refresh');
                                $("#homeLogger").text("list refreshed");
                                                                  },
                        function(error){
                                $("#homeLogger").text("error: "+error);
                        });
}

// ========== //
// Navigation //
// ========== //
function showTab(tab)
{
    $("#homeLogger").text("Selected Tab: "+tab);
    $("#tabs").find("div").hide();
    $("#"+tab.id).show();
}
```

Thank you very much for your help.
Rik

Comment: It could be `.show()`/`.hide()` problem, instead of using them make a custom class `.hide { display: none; }` and use `.addClass('hide');`/`.removeClass('hide');` to hide/show items.

Comment: I've just tried your solutions. It does not solve my problem: the contact tab shows only dividers and the right arrow to navigate to the contact.

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried to recreate the content page after dynamically adding content?

```
$('[data-role="content"]').trigger('create');
```

I gues your should do this b4 refreshing your ListViews (but after your for-loop has finished).

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, but also your solution does not lead to a good result.. I've tried it, but I get the dividers without the data in them. Up to now, I worked around this problem by reloading the data every time the user press on the tab button, but it is not very efficient, I guess...